# Excel consecutive numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to do some data analysis on excel and having some trouble.

So the problem is I need to make the last consecutive number on a list count but the rest needs to deleted to 0. For example, column A has the first number as a single consecutive number "1" therefore column B's equivalent number stands and is converted to column C as "1". But the next numbers in "A" are 1 and 2, the last consecutive number in this case "2" stands and so column B's equivalent is transferred as 0 to column C but the equivalent for "1" is 0 regardless of what is in column B.

Another way of putting this is that if I have in column A 1,2,3 and column B 1,1,1 then column C should have an answer of 0,0,1 as only the last number of a consecutive chain is valid and the others will be converted to 0. So this can be again column A 1,2 and column B 0,0 then column C will be 0,0 because only the last number is taken, coincidentally, this is also 0.

Thanks for your help in advance!

BEFORE

```
A   B   C
1   1   
1   0   
2   0   
1   1   
2   1   
1   0   
1   1   
1   1   
2   1   
1   1   
2   1   
3   1   
1   0   
1   1   
1   1   
2   1   
1   0   
2   0   
3   0
```

AFTER

```
A   B   C
1   1   1
1   0   0
2   0   0
1   1   0
2   1   1
1   0   0
1   1   1
1   1   0
2   1   1
1   1   0
2   1   0
3   1   1
1   0   0
1   1   1
1   1   0
2   1   1
1   0   0 
2   0   0
3   0   0
```

Comment: I'm afraid your question is quite confusing. Can you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1221024/edit) to explain more precisely? It's OK to use lots of words and lots of examples to make things crystal clear :)

Comment: Do you start with just column A and then your results are column B and C? Maybe show us a before and after. The before being what you start with and the after what your desired output would be

Comment: Thanks for your comments - I have updated the question and hopefully it is now clearer.

Comment: I still don't follow your logic... So based on what you said, you look down the column A for the first consecutive list. It starts with 1 then another 1. So the first C column becomes a 1. That part makes sense. Then you start your list below the first 1 in A - 1 then 2 then 1. Since the list ended at 2 wouldn't C get a 1 there? but you have a 0

Comment: C would get a 1 if corresponding B was a 1. Because in this case B is a 0, that number is valid and is kept as 0 but the number above is converted to 0.

Comment: If you then look at the next set in column A. A has 1,2 and B has 1,1 therefore C will be 0,1 because we take the A-2 to be valid so B-1 value is copied into C spot. We take A-1 to be invalid so B-1 value is changed to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you're checking the last consecutive figure in column A, and displaying the same rows entry in column B as the product for column C? In which case this seems to work:

=If(A1>=A2,B1,0)

Comment: Just tested this and it seems to work. I have also come across this formula which also works. ****************

"C1" =IF(AND(A1=1,B1=1,A2<>2),1,0) ********************************** "C2 onwards" =IF(AND(A2=1,B2=1,A3<>2),1,IF(AND(A2<>1,A2=A1+1,A2<>A3-1,B2=1),1,0))

Comment: Can't seem to get that second formula to work, although I can see what it's trying to do. Still, If a simpler formula will give you the result you need it might be worth not getting too complicated.

Comment: Think for the 2nd formula you need to use the first line in the top cell and the second line for the cells below that. Yes I agree, your solution is much less complicated and has been very helpful in saving time.

Answer (score 0):

The formula in the answer above will give the wrong result in some circumstances.  Suppose column A has 1,1,2,2,1...  In that case, the second "2" will trigger using the value in column B rather than zero.

A more general solution is given below, assuming the original question can be restated as follows:

For each number in column A that is the last number in a group of ascending numbers, the number in column C must be set equal to the number in column B.  This also happens when the number in column A is 1 and is NOT part of an ascending series.  Otherwise column C is set to zero.

If I have stated the problem correctly, here is a method that works (at least it reproduces column C in your AFTER table). The first row is a special case that is left as an exercise for the reader.  :-)

1. Numbers that are the last in a group of ascending numbers are 1 greater that the previous number and NOT 1 less that the succeeding number.  i.e. this expression will be true for those numbers:
   AND(A2-A1=1,A3-A2<>1)
2. The 1’s that are not part of an ascending series must be equal to 1 and not 1 less than the succeeding number.  i.e. this expression will be true for those numbers:
   AND(A1=1,A2-A1<>1)
3. Putting it all together:
   = IF(OR((AND(A2-A1=1,A3-A2<>1),AND(A2=1,A3-A2<>1)),B2,0)

Type this equation in C2 and fill down.